# How can I exclude a point from a Region Plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to exclude the point {0,0} from: `RegionPlot[0 < x^2 + (y^2)/4 <= 1 , {x, 2, -2}, {y, 2, -2}]`

Comment: What does it mean to exclude a point from a plot? Do you want to put a marker there? Remember, a point in a continuous coordinate system is infinitesimally small.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've explained it wrong. What I want is for point (0,0) to be marked, to represent that it is not included in the region